# How to integrate topshelf to an existing windows service project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-services, topshelf

I want to be able to use the TopShelf debugging abilities of my service in Visual Studio.

A lot of the [examples](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-windows-service-in-net-with-topshelf/) and [documentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FUa8RzWpJI0) out there refer to creating a Windows Console project in Visual Studio **first**, and **then** adding TopShelf, OWIN, etc

However, in my case I already have a perfectly good and working Windows Service project called QShipsService.sln, etc... and it uses a simple Connected Service (admittedly to old SOAP legacy services).

Can someone please direct me or provide an example of how to use TopShelf, with an existing **non-Console** like project?

Comment: If your existing project is already a windows service, what do you need TopShelf for?

Comment: @ZoharPeled err to debug the service. Now remove that downvote please.

Comment: Anyone could have downvoted.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the pain of SO

Comment: Sorry, not my donevote. I'm not aure how this will help. I do know you cam run a service in debog mode, but I don't remember how it's actually done. With TopShelf you just hit F5 and since the code is a console app it's just as easy to debug as any other console app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my own solution...

The assumption I made was the default Windows Service project defaulting to wanting to register the program as a service and kick off the `OnOpen()` and `OnClose()` methods, once the service is running.

In my case I wanted to re-use an existing service that was based on a Timer(), and it would kick in every 4 hours to call a SOAP call and return some data. What I didn't realise was the `ServiceConfigurator` was trying to call its own `Open()` and `Close()` methods.

So I commented out the `OnOpen` and `OnClose` methods and allowed the configurator to call my worker process via `Open()` method instead, which is what I was meant to have done the first time!

For the noobs out there like me, here is the code...

```
//using System.ServiceProcess;
using Topshelf;

namespace QShipsService
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HostFactory.Run(
                configure =>
                {
                    configure.Service<QShipsService.QshipsService>(
                        service =>
                        {
                            service.ConstructUsing(s => new QShipsService.QshipsService());
                            service.WhenStarted(s => s.QStart());
                            service.WhenStopped(s => s.QStop());
                        });

                    //Setup Account that window service use to run.
                    configure.RunAsLocalSystem();

                    //add details and names about the service
                    configure.SetServiceName("QshipsService");
                    configure.SetDisplayName("QshipsService");
                    configure.SetDescription("QshipsService Windows Service to extract data from the QSHIPS SOAP service. Data is recorded and maintained inside the SPOT's database in POT-DB.");
                });


            //## USE THIS IF WE'RE NOT USING TOPSHELF !! ##
            //    //this loads and starts the QshipsService (see QshipsService.cs program)
            //    ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            //    ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
            //    {
            //        new QShipsService.QshipsService()
            //    };
            //    ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
    }
}
```